# hibernate-cfg.xml and property placeholders

Tags: spring, hibernate

I create my `hibernate-cfg.xml` file using the Ant hibernatecfg task in my build file. I reference that file in my sessionFactory bean (`org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean`) in the configLocation property (`classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml`).
In my bean definitions file, I also have a propertyConfigurer (`org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`).

Will the propertyConfigurer do substitutions in the `hibernate.cfg.xml` file or do I have to hard-code everything in that file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring won't resolve properties in `hibernate.cfg.xml`.